# EagleHorn - Loading a worker in a model

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am using [Eaglehorn](http://eaglehorn.org/) framework for developing an application. I am stuck at a point where i need to use the session worker in one of my model. The documentation says i can load the worker in the below way.

```
class mymodel extends R {

    function __construct() {

       R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . MYSQL_DB, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD);

    }     

    function get_user() {
        $s = $this->load->worker('eh_session'); //does not work
    }

}
```

How can i use worker in this case or is it possible to access workers from model ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is getting extended with R (RedbeanPHP) and not EH_Base. `$this->load` will not work inside model. However, you can use the session worker in the below way.

```
$base = eh()->get('base');
$s = $base->load->worker('eh_session');
```